# "There is not enough space on the disk" error when my azure function app downloads a large file from blob storage

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have an azure function app, which downloads files from blob storage into the temp folder, manipulates the files, and then uploads new files into blob storage

This is working fine, except when I try and download big videos (the one that I'm testing with is about 600mb), in which case I'm getting a **There is not enough space on the disk** error. Downloading smaller files works fine

If I run some code to output the available drive space to the logs, I can see that there is plenty of available space on the drive that I'm downloading the file to (about 4GB free)

Is there a limit to the size of files that I can download into a function app's temp folder? I can't see any reference to a limit like that in any documentation

---

The downloading code isn't anything special, but here it is just to be complete...

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");
    webClient.DownloadFile(blobFileUri, filePath);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The consumption plan for Azure Functions provides 1GB of storage.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale:

> The storage limit is the total content size in temporary storage
>   across all apps in the same App Service plan. Consumption plan uses
>   Azure Files for temporary storage.

If you have already used more than 0.4GB of this, and it tries to write the 0.6GB file to temporary storage, it may exceed 1GB and fail.

The premium plan provides 250GB.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the temporary directory like this:

```
string tmpFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
```

Then you will get about 500 MB on consumption plan. If you are using premium it is at least 10 GB, probably a lot more.

But you could store data on a network drive if you run out of space. Get the directory like this:

```
string remoteTempDirectory = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@$"%HOME%/render/{DateTime.Today:yyyy-MM-dd}-{Guid.NewGuid()}");
```

When your function is complete remember to remove the directory. The network drive is about 5-10 times slower than the local disc.

This function will test how much data you could store on your local drive:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger logger)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    string tmpFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
    logger.LogInformation($"Testing maximum file size with {tmpFileName }");
    string bestSize = "?";
    byte[] data = new byte[50 * 1024 * 1024];

    for (int fiftyMegs = 1; fiftyMegs <= 10; fiftyMegs++)
    {
        try
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Saving file with size { fiftyMegs * 50 } MB...");

            using FileStream file = new FileStream(tmpFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            file.Position = file.Length;
            file.Write(data);
            bestSize = $"Saving file with size { fiftyMegs * 50 } MB succeded.";

            logger.LogInformation($"Saving file with size { fiftyMegs * 50 } MB succeded.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bestSize += Environment.NewLine + $"Saving file with size { fiftyMegs * 50 } MB failed: {ex.Message}";
            logger.LogError($"Saving file with size { fiftyMegs * 50 } MB failed: {ex.Message}");
            break;
        }
    }

    File.Delete(tmpFileName);
    logger.LogInformation($"Saving file test completed.");
    bestSize += Environment.NewLine + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();

    return new OkObjectResult(bestSize);
}
```